# Gilead vs RequestFactory for GWT

Tags: database, hibernate, orm, gwt, dto

What are the pros and cons for each? Which is your favorite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Knego lists out 3 disadvantages of RequestFactory [here](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/using-gwt-requestfactory-with-objectify/#comment-4538).

> I tried RequestFactory for our own
>   project but decided to abandon it for
>   the following reasons:
>
> 1. RequestFactory can not be used to transfer Maps. Old plain GWT-RPC can
>      do it.
> 2. You have to manually write proxy interface for every entity. This is
>      like writing DTOs – there is a lot of
>      duplicate code.
> 3. When writing proxy interfaces, there is no type-safety: for every
>      property in entity there is
>      corresponding method in proxy
>      interface. This has to be managed
>      manually. When project evolves there
>      is bound to be changes to entities.
>      Developers have to keep this in mind
>      and sync code manually, which is error
>      prone.
>
> In GWT there is now a new option to do
>   custom serialization without DTOs or
>   super-sourcing: CustomFieldSerializer.
>
> I used this to serialize datastore’s
>   Entity (used by objectigfy’s
>   @PrePersist/@PostLoad)